# How can I solve 'code 2' error during compilation/deployment of Qt project MyIHM?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

"C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet MyIHM
How can I solve this error?

I checked the C make file but it seems thar everything is right

Comment: The error code may mean `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. You need to look at the build output to find the actual problem and add that to your question.